# How to make .cab in ruby with ruby-libmspack gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cab

I am working on POC to create .cab file (MS compress format) in ruby on rails application. I found this **[ruby-libmspack](https://github.com/davispuh/ruby-libmspack)** that provide  bindings to create .cab files. But the gem seriously lacks examples. I did lot of research on google but didnt find any sample code to compress files into .cab archive.

Did anyone knows how to create cab archive using ruby-libmspack gem? Is there any other way to create .cab archive in ruby on rails application?

Answer (score 0):

Not Sure About Ruby-libmspack, but lcab can create CAB files on Linux.